# Chrome Extension: browserAction Click button work once

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on Chrome Extension that opens link on clicking of extension Icon. Manifest is given below.

Issue is, once data is fetched and open links, it does not do again on same page.

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name" : "xxx",
    "description" : "Open links",
    "version" : "1.1",
    "background" : {
        "scripts" : ["jquery.js","background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts" : [{
        "matches" : ["*://xxx/*"],
        "js" : ["jquery.js","script.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }],
"icons":
    {
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "48": "icon48.png"
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "script.js",
        "jquery.js",
        "background.js"
    ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "xxx",
        "default_icon": "icon16.png"
      }
}
```

**background.js**

```
var l = 0;
var lnks = null;
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab)
{
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs)
    {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {method: "sendHTML"}, function(response)
            {

                var val = null;
                if(response.data != null) {
                    lnks = parse_links(response.data);
                    val = setInterval(function(){
                        var total = lnks.length;
                        if (l < lnks.length) {
                            console.log(lnks[l]);
                            chrome.tabs.create({ url: lnks[l] });
                            l++;
                        } else {
                            clearInterval(val);
                        }


                    }, 5000);

                }

            }
        );
    });

});

function openTab(url) {
    l++;
}

function parse_links(body) {
    var jq = $(body);
    var tble = jq.find("table");
    var legit_links = [];
    var link = null;

    jq.find('table a').each(function() {
        //val = setInterval(openTab,4000,lnks[i]);
        link = $(this).attr('href').trim();
        if(link.indexOf("?accountid") !== -1) {
            $(this).click();
            legit_links.push(link)

        }
    });

    return legit_links;

}
```

**script.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
//    alert('Message from View:\n'
//          + JSON.stringify(msg));
    if (msg.method === 'sendHTML')
    {
        sendResponse({ data:$("body").html()});
    }
});
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: @HaibaraAi Silly me. Question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to clear `l`, then the next time you click `browser action`, it remains the value of `lnks.length`.

Set `l = 0` when `clearInterval` will solve your problem.